# How can I set a configurable timeout value for a session in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session

I am new to Rails. We are using rails 3. I would like to know how I can set a configurable session timeout value for our Rails application.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Rails 3 config.action_controller.session does not work. You can configure the application's session data in the initializer file `config/initializers/session_store.rb`

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
        :key => '_my_session', 
        :expire_after => 30.minutes
```

Comment: thanks for youe answer i am looking for the same. Can you tell me how do i redirect to root file after session expire

Answer (score 2):

In environment file set:

```
config.action_controller.session = {
  :key          => 'whatever',
  :secret       => 'nottellingyou',
  :expire_after => 30.minutes
}


OR 


session :session_key => 'my_session_key'
session :session_expires => 1.day.from_now
```